# Как импортировать несколько модулей?

Tags: python, pycharm, модульность

Добрый день!

Начинаю изучать python.
Как импортировать несколько модулей?
Второй раз когда импорт пишу, он почему-то его как будто коментирует. В чем причина? Подскажете?

Скрин:

[image]

Comment: @kelevra, наведите курсор на подчеркнутый текст и подождите, чтобы PyCharm выдал вам подсказку

Comment: Пишет unused import statement/
Все равно не пойму.

Comment: @kelevra, вы не используете этот модуль, следовательно, его необязательно импортировать. Как только вы начнете использовать этот импорт, PyCharm перестанет затемнять его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm серым показывает неиспользуемые модули (о чем и говорит сообщение "`unused import statement`"). Обратитесь к любой функции из `random` и импорт перестанет быть серым.

P.S. Кстати, `randrange` подчеркивает красным, потому что в вашем случае его нужно вызывать как `random.randrange(4)`. Как только добавите `random` перед `randrange`, его перестанет подчеркивать, и `import random` перестанет быть серым.